# Why does Visual Studio assemble mov eax, [edx][ebx][ecx][edi] without complaint?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

In Visual Studio, I wrote:

```
mov eax, [edx][ebx][ecx][edi]
```

But it assembles just fine.

Why it is not invalid effective address?

Comment: What do you expect `mov eax, [edx][ebx][ecx][edi]` to do?

Comment: nothing, I only wonder why it is correct effective adress.

Comment: It doesn't assemble with masm 6.14.8444. What does that instruction disassemble to?

Answer (score 7):

It appears to be a bug in more recent versions of MASM.

Using the following file as an example:

```
    .586

_TEXT   SEGMENT USE32
    mov eax, [edx][ebx][ecx][edi]
_TEXT   ENDS
    END
```

With MASM 6.11d this generates the following error:

```
t213a.asm(4) : error A2030: multiple index registers not allowed
```

With MASM 8.00.50727.42 or more recent there's no error, and the statement assembles to:

```
00000000: 8B 04 0F           mov         eax,dword ptr [edi+ecx]
```

So `[edx][ebx][ecx][edi]` is not a valid addressing mode. A bug in the version of MASM you're using is accepting it when it should be rejecting it as an error.

Comment: Thanks @Ross I found the same thing. You beat me to it. You have my upvote

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks, if it wasn't for your comment about 6.14.8444 I would've never have thought to try an older version of MASM to see if this is a regression.

Comment: That was the other @Michael ;-)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Oops. Sorry, Michael.